An alternative way to set the value of a variable in pocketpy wihout converting to a string
I am using pocketpy as an embedded interpreter for a C++ program. One thing I need to do is convert a std::vector<float> to a named pocketpy variable. I can do this by evaluating a string version and passing the string to the vm->exec method but that seems like an inefficient approach (vm is the pkpy::VM):
stringstream s;
s << "v = [" << x[0] << "," << x[1] << "," << x[2] << "]";
vm->exec(s.str());

I can create native pocketpy lists following the instructions:
List t;
t.push_back(py_var(vm, x[0]));
t.push_back(py_var(vm, x[1]));
t.push_back(py_var(vm, x[2]));
PyVar obj = py_var(vm, std::move(t));

That seems like it will be much more efficient but I then can't work out how to assign this to the variable v in the pocketpy virtual machine. It seems like such a basic thing to do that I must be missing something. Perhaps the string approach is the right way to go but the vector can be moderately big so it does not feel like a good option. Any help appreciated.

Write a conversion operator maybe?

Looks like you need pkpy_setglobal https://pocketpy.dev/c-api/stack/#variable-access

That's what I needed. pkpy_setglobal is the C interface and it relies on an internal stack so I'd rather not use that. However it is just a wrapper around the C++ and looking at the code it calls vm->_main->attr().set(pkpy::StrName("v"), obj) and that does the job.
